# Subtotal function calculation only working on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am trying to calculate a subtotal by multiplying the select variant price by the qty input value; but it's not quite working. For some reason the function only executes when I click on either the plus or minus button twice and the input value of the qty selector is always one value ahead; here is the code I have created so far:

The HTML

Snippet file loaded into product template

```
{% include 'quantity-picker-pdp' with id: quantity_id, value: 1, min: 0, max: current_variant.inventory_quantity %}
```

The qty picker for the product page

```
<!-- QTY selector PDP page -->
<div class="quantity-picker js-quantity-picker-pdp">
  {% if settings.quantity_selector_enabled %}
  <div class="quantity buttons_added mr-2" {% if value == min %}disabled{% endif %}>
    <input type="button" value="-" class="js-quantity-button-pdp minus js-minus" {% if can_add_to_cart != true and value == min %}disabled{% endif %}>
      <input type="number" id="{{ id }}" class="input-text qty text js-quantity-field-pdp" {% if min != blank %}min="{{ min }}"{% endif %}{% if max != blank %}max="{{ max }}"{% endif %} name="quantity" value="{{ value }}" autocomplete="off" {% if can_add_to_cart != true %}disabled{% endif %}>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="+" class="js-quantity-button-pdp plus js-plus" {% if value == max and can_add_to_cart != true %}disabled{% endif %}>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
<!-- end QTY selector PDP -->
```

The JS

```
  let
    addToCartFormSelector = '#add-to-cart-form',
    qtyPickerPlusPdp = '.js-plus',
    qtyPickerMinusPdp = '.js-minus',
    productOptionSelector = addToCartFormSelector + ' [name*=option]';

  let productForm = {

    onProductOptionChanged: function(event) {
      let
        $form = $(this).closest(addToCartFormSelector),
        selectedVariant = productForm.getActiveVariant($form);
        $form.trigger('form:change', [selectedVariant]);

    },
    getSubtotalPlus: function(event) {
      let
        $formRefPlus = $(this).closest(addToCartFormSelector),
        selectedVariant = productForm.getActiveVariant($formRefPlus),
        $qtyValPlus = $('.js-quantity-field-pdp'),
        quantityValue = parseInt($qtyValPlus.val());

        if (selectedVariant.inventory_quantity) {
          //calculate subtotal on pdp plus button
          $('#subtotal').text('SUB TOTAL:' + '$' + (selectedVariant.price * quantityValue / 100).toFixed(2)).change();
          //end calculate subtotal on pdp plus button
        }
      console.log(quantityValue);
      $formRefPlus.trigger('form:change', [selectedVariant]);
    },
    getSubtotalMinus: function(event) {
      let
        $formRefMinus = $(this).closest(addToCartFormSelector),
        selectedVariant = productForm.getActiveVariant($formRefMinus),
        $qtyValMinus = $('.js-quantity-field-pdp'),
        quantityValueMinus = parseInt($qtyValMinus.val());

        if (selectedVariant.inventory_quantity) {
          //calculate subtotal on pdp minus button
          $('#subtotal').html('SUB TOTAL:' + '$' + ((selectedVariant.price * (quantityValueMinus) / 100) - selectedVariant.price / 100).toFixed(2));
          //end calculate subtotal on pdp minus button
        }
    },
    getActiveVariant: function($form) {
      let
        variants = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($form.attr('data-variants')));
        formData = $form.serializeArray();
        formOptions = {
          option1: null,
          option2: null,
          option3: null
        },
        selectedVariant = null;

        $.each(formData, function(index, item) {
          if (item.name.indexOf('option') !== -1 ) {
            formOptions[item.name] = item.value;
          }
        });

        $.each(variants, function(index, variant) {
          if (variant.option1 === formOptions.option1 && variant.option2 === formOptions.option2 && variant.option3 === formOptions.option3) {
            selectedVariant = variant;
            return false;
          }
        });

        return selectedVariant;
    },
    init: function() {
      $(document).on('change', productOptionSelector, productForm.onProductOptionChanged);
      $(document).on('click change', qtyPickerPlusPdp, productForm.getSubtotalPlus);
      $(document).on('click change', qtyPickerMinusPdp, productForm.getSubtotalMinus);
    }
  };
  productForm.init();
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - you're 90% of the way there we just need a bit of HTML to go with it.

Comment: Server code is less useful, we cant run it. We need the _output_ HTML

Comment: Where/when do you call `productForm.init();`?  Try putting that line in doc.ready.  Your code needs to be *complete* to demonstrate the issue, otherwise it's just guess work.